# ImportError: No module named bs4?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to import library: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`.

When I run script I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 9, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named bs4
root@srvr [/home/public_html/grabber/similar]#
```

When I try install:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

I get the following error:

```
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.5.1-py2.6.egg
```

Script is:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages')
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: You installed BeautifulSoup for Python 2.6, but according to your tag, you are using Python 3.x.

Comment: why are you installing it for python **2.6** and then using a hack to (try to) import it in python **3**? Just install it for python3! You may need to use `pip3` insted of `pip`.

Comment: You have **two** Python installations (at least). You have BeautifulSoup installed in the Python 2.6 setup, not in the other. Use `python3 -m pip install beatifulsoup4` to use the `pip` module attached to `python3`. You *may* have a `pip3` command line available.

Comment: Can you extend your answer by steps?

Comment: I do: `Python -V` and get: `Python 2.7`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You installed BeautifulSoup for Python 2.6, but according to your tag, you are using Python 3.x. To install explicitly for Python 3, use `pip3` instead of `pip`, i.e.

```
pip3 install beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: Or python3 -m pip

Comment: Yes, I use Python 3, how can I install this package?

Comment: I do: `Python -V` and get: `Python 2.7`

Comment: Then why did you tag your question with 'Python 3.x'? You might have multiple Pythons installed. What does `print(sys.version)` show when executed inside your script?

Comment: i am using the mac os , the system default python is 2.7. i have install the 3.6 manually , so this case works for me.  i have install the beautifulsoup4 with "sudo pip install beautifulsoup4" but this is for python 2.7 ;  so make sure the python version  you are running, if the version is 3.X  you should install the beautifulsoup4 with pip3

Answer (score 4):

If you try this on Mac OS X do the following:

1. Go to the official website: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/
2. Download the .tar.gz package
3. Unpack it
4. Go to the unpacked folder
5. Type: `python setup.py install`

Comment: This should be a top solution! fixed it for me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Pycharm, go to preferences - project interpreter - install bs4. If you try to install BeautifulSoup, it will still show that no module named bs4.